# Net::FTP::File bug in dir_hashref()?

Tags: perl, ftp

I'm using the `Net::FTP::File` module to get a list of directories in a remote path. It seemed to work fine until I stepped on this case where a directory named `en` shows up as just `n`, details:

```
'n' => {
    'Bytes' => '4096',
    'Group' => 'client3',
    'Owner' => '5004',
    'Path' => 'n',
    'Last Modified Year/Time' => '17:59',
    'Permissions' => 'drwxrwxr-x',
    'Last Modified Day' => '17',
    'Link To' => undef,
    'Number of Links' => '7',
    'Last Modified Month' => 'Jan'
},
```

the directory on the server has the correct name (`en`) same owner/group/permissions as other directories that display fine.

I reduced the test case to the minimum so I know the problem doesn't depend on other bugs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP::File;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

my $ftp = new Net::FTP($site);
$ftp->login($user, $pass);
print Dumper $ftp->dir_hashref;
```

is there anything I'm doing wrong that might cause this error? Or is it a bug in the dir_hashref() function of the module?

Alternatively, what's another (convenient) way to get only the directories in an FTP list? Standard `Net::FTP` provides the `dir()` method, but it's just a list of `ls -l` like strings that have to be parsed.

Comment: Using your code snippet on a lenny box, I couldn't reproduce...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it either, it just happens on a specific server (which runs debian lenny btw)

Comment: I would guess that the filename itself is fishy, i.e., contains unprintable characters or something like that.

Comment: Directory name is fine, just regular `e` and `n`. Solved now using `parse_dir` from `File::Listing` module on the list returned by regular `$ftp->dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to suspect the filename contains an unusual character.

Do you see the file with the correct name if you use a normal FTP client to connect to that server?

Try passing the Debug parameter to the Net::FTP constructor, for instance:

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($hostname, Debug => 1);
```

That should get you some more debug info, in particular the dialog between your script and the server, which will likely be of use.

Comment: I see no problem in the filename neither with a normal FTP client, nor directly via SSH shell on the server. The directory is perfectly accessible via http request, can `cd` into it etc. The output of `$ftp->dir` is fine too.

Comment: Presumably you've found a bug in Net::FTP::File, then.  Looking at the code, I believe it might be caused by line 50: $path = substr( $path, 1 );    # remove first space that is there but is not part of the name

Comment: If you want to help the author, you could report the bug via https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Net-FTP-File so that it can be fixed.  (There's already a similar-sounding bug there, but the reporter of that claims the problem only occurs for single-character names; it may well be the same problem, though.)

Comment: Thanks David, you're right that's the line that causes the bug. I'll report it.

Comment: You should add the note about the bug in the answer for more visibility

Comment: @kemp Maybe you'd want to check the version of `Net::FTP::File` before submitting that bug. A fresh CPAN install of that module showed no such bug on my box...

Comment: I have the latest version: 0.06